# filtering mongodb documents using distance

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I struggle filtering documents using the coordinates of the user (max distance).

My request looks like this:

```js
app.post('/item', checkAuth, function(request, response) {

    var location = request.body.location;
    var distance = request.body.distance;

    Item.find( {  "location": {
        $near: {   $geometry: {  type: "Point",
                               coordinates: [location.longitude, location.latitude] },
                               $maxDistance: distance
                              
               }
    } }, function(err, items) {
        if (err) {
            response.status(500).send({error: err});
        } else {
            response.send({items : items,
                           message: 'Fetching items successful'
                          });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What is distance number you place to request? And you sure in right longitude/latitude you passed to request?

Comment: testing with some default coordinates from my iPhone (Californian)   and distance value of 10.0

Comment: 10.0 meters. And you shure about right data in database? I mean your location intersect with any values on database?

Comment: the thing is , its not that i'm getting zero results . i'm getting  an error : "unable to find index for $geoNear query" .  i did some digging about it and it's looks like it's related to the index , but still have no clue what am i doing wrong.

Comment: Please post your mongoose model definition